# Is it possible to findout if someone used date option in git commit?

Tags: git, gitlab

Trying to figure out strange structure of a git repository. The chronological order of commits doesn't make sense.

Is it possible to find out if someone used `--date` option during git commit?

Comment: FWIW, the default view of git log shows you the "author date", not the "commit date".  You can use one of the other formats to see that (for example, `--pretty=fuller`).  Depending on the project, when and how things were merged, there could be big discrepancies between author date and commit date.  That might be what you are seeing.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister can someone fake both author date and commit date?

Comment: It's probably rebase, not fake date.

Comment: Why does it matter if the git commits are not in chronological order?

Comment: @evolutionxbox perhaps there is a concern of tampering

Comment: Tampering? Then you have a bigger problem.

Comment: @ozgur Yes, they can.

Comment: @JohnSzakmeister Question remains. Is it possible to determine it?

Comment: @ozgur if I had an answer, I would’ve left it as an answer.   As far as I know, no, there is no way to determine if they’ve been tampered with—except the case where the author date is newer than the commit date.  Also, “git log” doesn’t always show things in the best order... you can use some of the other options to get something that’s more meaningful to you (such as “date order” or “topo order”).  Also, depending on how you are looking at things and what has happened, history simplification might be occurring too.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to find out if someone used `--date` option during git commit?

No.  That is, commits *do* have date stamps, but there's no telling where the date stamp came from.

In fact, every commit has *two* date-and-time stamps:

```
$ git cat-file -p HEAD | sed 's/@/ /'
tree f8fa7543afb10d56e2138e2a7313aa8c2c93f3ba
parent bc7a3d4dc04dd719e7c8c35ebd7a6e6651c5c5b6
parent a0ba80001a42eeacae94e3503c3e7d4bf7f2f2e1
author Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1580160367 -0800
committer Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com> 1580160367 -0800

Sync with maint

* maint:
  .mailmap: fix erroneous authorship for Johannes Schindelin
```

The *author* line gives the name, email address, and date-and-time stamp for the author, and the *committer* line gives the name, email address, and date-and-time stamp for the committer.  They are often exactly the same, as here, but not always.  The date-and-time are in the form of the two numbers: the first is a Unix-like time value (count of seconds since 1970) and the second is the time zone offset.

By default, when copying a commit (as with `git rebase` or `git cherry-pick`), Git keeps the original author data, and writes new committer data.  When `git log` sorts commits,<sup>1</sup> it uses the committer timestamp by default, although as [John Szakmeister noted in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60238120/is-it-possible-to-findout-if-someone-used-date-option-in-git-commit#comment106550543_60238120), it *shows* the author information, including author timestamp, by default.

> can someone fake both author date and commit date?

Yes—plus, for a new commit, those default to reading the computer's clock, which could be wrong.  By "wrong" I don't just mean off a few nanoseconds, which is bad enough but doesn't affect Git (Git's resolution is whole seconds), but off by minutes, or hours, or even years.

Because the hash ID of any commit is the SHA-1 checksum of its (meta)data—its contents as shown above, with the `tree` and `parent` and `author` lines and so on—it is extremely difficult to tamper with any *existing* commit.  You not only have to break SHA-1 (not impossible any more) but also make the commit data "look right".  This means that if you have an existing repository that you trust, you don't have to worry about someone secretly replacing existing commits with new commits with the same hash ID: that's (a) way too hard and (b) profitless.  You can be mildly concerned with wrong or faked timestamps in *new* commits, but since your Git repository is *yours*, you can simply vet them before you allow them in.<sup>2</sup>

Note that the input data that result in the commit's hash ID *include the hash IDs of the parent commits*.  This means that the commits themselves form a [Merkle tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merkle_tree).  Hence, the fact that some commit *H* passes some sort of cryptographic test implies that *H*'s parent *G* also passes that test, which implies that *G*'s parent *F* passes that test, and so on.  So you can GPG-sign particular commits using an annotated tag, which puts a pretty strong digital signature on the tag.  While SHA-1 itself is relatively weak, you can, if you're that worried, inspect each commit to make sure it has no "random junk" data area where someone can write bytes to construct a desired hash.  Then, if you trust the GPG signature, you can trust all the commits leading *up to* that signed commit—at least to the extent that you trust whoever *made* the GPG signature.

(It's possible to GPG-sign each commit, but in many work-flows, this is impractical.  When Git moves to SHA256, concerns over the relative weakness of SHA1 may abate, too.)

---

<sup>1</sup>Explaining just *when* `git log` actually sorts commits is a bit tricky.  In many or even most cases, `git log` is following a simple chain of commits, one commit at a time, so that there is no opportunity for sorting.  The command must be following *more than one commit* at the particular time.

The way `git log` works is this:

- You start it with one or more *starting point* commits.  (It might be more appropriate to call these *ending points* because Git works backwards, but `git log` itself is going to start here.)
- These commits go into a priority queue.  The priority is determined by the sort criteria.  So if you start Git with two or more commits, they get sorted here.
- Then, as `git log` walk the graph, it pulls one commit *out* of the priority queue, examines it, determines whether to show it, and shows it or doesn't according to the *show or don't show* criteria you've specified.  Then it puts none, some, or all of that commit's *parent commit hash IDs* into the priority queue.  So if the commit has two or more parents, and `git log` puts them all into the priority queue, they get sorted here, at this point.

Different options to `git log` affect the sorting, the displaying criteria, and the set of parent hashes that get put into the queue.  For instance, the `--first-parent` option directs `git log` to insert only the *first* parent of any commit.

The most complicated of all of these is `git log`'s *history simplification* mode, in which it may omit some parents entirely and/or "rewrite" the parent hashes attached to a commit (temporarily in memory only—the actual repository is not, and cannot be, altered).  History simplification is, for instance, how Git synthesizes a "file history" when you run `git log --follow file`: there is no such thing as file history, but by taking the *commit* history and dropping many commits and fiddling with the linkages in memory, Git can make a *pretend* file history, and show that instead of the actual history.

<sup>2</sup>This is easier said than done.  If your repository accepts `git push` requests, you can vet incoming commits in pre-receive and update hooks.  You have to write these hooks yourself, and they are nontrivial to write correctly.  If you `git fetch` to obtain new commits, you still have to write your own code to do this kind of screening, but this time, instead of having a pre-receive or update hook do it, you would probably create or update your own branch names after letting `git fetch` update remote-tracking names as usual.